# In Ruby or Rails, is there a "duration_for { fetch_some_data() }" and it can print "fetch_some_data() done, took 2.1 seconds"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, is there already such a function?

So that we can use

```
<%= duration_for { fetch_some_data() } %>
```

and it will print

```
fetch_some_data() done, result is:
  {"status" : 1, "data" : {"x" : 123} }
(took 2.1 seconds)
```

Otherwise, what is a good way to write that in Ruby?  (more like a method, so we can't use the UNIX's `time` to do it)

Comment: Query and view/partial rendering times, as well as overall times for reach request, are all listed in Rails' logs.

Comment: I see, that helps.  If it can be on screen for easier debugging, that would be convenient

Comment: But what if `fetch_some_data()` is actually doing an HTTP request?  will that be in the log?

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.ms do
  fetch_some_data()
end
```

will return the time it takes to complete the block in milliseconds.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Benchmark

Comment: Generally take a look into the [Benchmark](http://apidock.com/ruby/Benchmark) class, it has a couple of useful methods.

Comment: In Rails, it won't print out the result returned by `fetch_some_data()`, and the `Benchmark.ms` returns something like 1213.238 meaning 1.213 seconds... but I suppose it can be `"took %.3f seconds" % [Benchmark.ms { sleep 1.23456 } / 1000]` to print that out.  what is the detail so that it works well with the view and application helper?

Comment: also it is a bit messy in HAML as the `do` is automatically closed by HAML, and you can't easily get the `/ 1000]` part in there.  Can you give a solution that's actually as clean as `<%= duration_for { fetch_some_data() } %>` or in HAML `= duration_for { fetch_some_data() }`